Abrir una URL con una sesion iniciada y presionar un boton con selenium python
Trato de entrar a mercado libre en el cual ya tengo mi sesion iniciada pero al momento de abrir el navegador con selenium python, se abre el navegador pero con un mensaje que dice "El navegador esta bajo control remoto(Razon: Marionette) y la sesion de mercado libre no esta iniciada con mi usuario.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.mx/MLM-610008329-silla-eames-wagner-comedor-sillas-moderna-minimalistas-retro-_JM?variation=55843477730#reco_item_pos=4&reco_backend=item_decorator&reco_backend_type=function&reco_client=home_items-decorator-legacy&reco_id=cf0d3f6a-868e-47ee-a6eb-85296dee6b67&c_id=/home/bookmarks-recommendations-seed/element&c_uid=9501d45e-9d25-4015-91d6-63f3d3b5c413&da_id=bookmark&da_position=1&id_origin=/home/dynamic_access&da_sort_algorithm=ranker")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id("P0-1").click()

como puedo hacer para que python o selenium puedan entrar a mi navegador principal con la sesion iniciada en mi usuario en mercado libre?

Primero necesitamos saber cual es el navegador principal (siempre abres moxilla firefox, pero puede que el usuario tenga chrome). Hay una API que resume esto, no se si la quieras usar: webbrowser para ello: import webbrowser;webbrowser.open("https://google.com",1);

Y para iniciar con la sesion en firefox con selenum intenta:
from selenium import webdriver;options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions(); driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options). Recomiendo leer y para iniciar sesion: from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile;from selenium import webdriver;options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions();firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile();firefox_profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False);options.profile = firefox_profile;driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

Lectura recomendada (en inglés): Efficient Login Session Management in Selenium-Python
